# How can i script entering as administrator to cmd?

Tags: python, windows, service, command-line-interface, elevated-privileges

I'm writing this script in python, which needs to access to administrator privileges so it can start and stop services in Windows. I've found this line

```
runas /user:Administrator cmd
```

But it opens a prompt, which i can't fill with print, and even if i could, it opens cmd as administrator in a new window. And with powershell line

```
start-process powershell -verb runas
```

it does the same, opens a window to enter user and password.

I need it to run all through so it starts a service when it's detected it's down. How can i do that, knowing i need administrator privileges on it, and that it needs to be a pipelined script?

Comment: In Windows, to my knowledge, you can't elevate your current `cmd` process to admin like `sudo` would. You can make your program entry point a batch file with `runas /user:Administrator "python my_program.py"` which would achieve your desired result.

Comment: it asks me for the password after i enter the script, do you know how can it be entered automatized?

Comment: Check out : https://superuser.com/questions/788924/is-it-possible-to-automatically-run-a-batch-file-as-administrator

Comment: @JonSG it won't work, it doesn't find the getadmin.vbs file, using the pipelined script below posted

Answer (score 0):

Best solution i got was to cron the script on the admin account, so i didn't need to answer for admin credentials